# 'Method exceeds compiler instruction limit' message on well under 64K method

Tags: android, methods, limit

I often see repeated messages like this in my log:

```
Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 29278 in void com.xxxxxxapp.xxxxxx.MyGLRenderer.onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)
Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 29278 in void com.xxxxxxapp.xxxxxx.MyGLRenderer.onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)
Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 29278 in void com.xxxxxxapp.xxxxxx.MyGLRenderer.onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)
```

Breaking the code down typically gives the same message with a smaller number:

```
Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 22400 in void com.xxxxxxapp.xxxxxx.MyGLRenderer.onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)
```

I thought 64000 was the magic number to keep under here. My game code has always appeared to run fine despite nagging messages like this, and it's not just in the opengl onDrawFrame method. I've gotten similar messages in my update method for well under 64K, although update code is easier to break down than drawing code.

Searches for 'Method exceeds compiler instruction limit' have just gotten me links to the dreaded 'Dalvik compiler limit on 64K methods' error. Do I have to keep ignoring this?

Comment: maybe 64k is bytes  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of `Compiler::IsPathologicalCase`:

> Skip compilation for pathologically large methods - either by instruction count or num vregs.
>
> Dalvik uses 16-bit uints for instruction and register counts.  We'll limit to a quarter of that, which also guarantees we cannot overflow our 16-bit internal Quick SSA name space.

Source: [compiler.cc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/compiler/compiler.cc).

16-bit `uint` can represent a maximum value of `65535`, divided by `4`, equals `16383.75`.

Raising the target level from `Dalvik` to `ART` might circumvent it; because `Dalvik` and [javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html) seem to be incompatible, due to instruction count.

The register count is being checked after that, therefore this doesn't seem to the issue here.

Patching `compiler.cc` would also be an option, despite not a good one.

- when `4` would be `2`, this would permit double the amount.
- when not `return true` it should also proceed with the compilation.

This is the check, which is at fault:

```
if (accessor.InsnsSizeInCodeUnits() >= UINT16_MAX / 4) {
  LOG(INFO) << "Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: "
            << accessor.InsnsSizeInCodeUnits()
            << " in " << dex_file.PrettyMethod(method_idx);
  return true;
}
```

Disclaimer: without the least guarantee of "no side effects".

Comment: Looks like my update and draw methods are 'pathologically' large, lol. Nice source.

Comment: @Androidcoder probably not your's but the compilation altogether. stripping unused methods also might help; just no clue if this happens before or after that check happens. the optimal solution would be to get below the 16k instruction count.

Comment: Stripping unused methods doesn't matter, because this error is triggered when the method is called. Compilation fails the first time the method is called, so the next call is also the "first" and fails again, and the next, and the next… Compiling a large method takes CPU time and battery power, so doing this in a loop is quite a problem. (In my case it concerns parsing using [javacc](https://javacc.github.io/javacc/) and a middlingly complex grammar. Hello there, search engines.)

Comment: As the "method exceeds compiler instruction limit" entry it is only logged at the "Info" level, is it only an advisory that does not actually impact app functionality? What harm is caused?

Comment: It causes that method to be interpreted, ie. it runs more slowly. This may or may not be a problem. Most functions don't contain performance hotspots, after all.

Answer (score -2):

to skip this error you can use proGaurd minify Enabled option for both your release or debug version. if this does not help, use MultiDex application. for more information refer to this documentation.[MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Comment: The question concerns the number of instructions in a single method; android's limit is lower than the JVM's limit. Multidex deals with the number of methods in an application.