# Method exceeds compiler instruction limit

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-room

Before I wrote this question, i've searched in all proposed answers, "stackoverflow" shows me but nothing fit my case.

My problem:
I wrote Room migration to copy old data from a table and add it to another table, and i need to specify all the columns in the query. I have something like 130 columns.

```
 database.execSQL("INSERT INTO newTable(col1, ..n) SELECT col1, .... coln FROM oldTable")
```

When i executed my migration, i got this error:

```
method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 16602 in androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper$ValidationResult
```

Thx for your helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960389/method-exceeds-compiler-instruction-limit-message-on-well-under-64k-method

Comment: @Robert thx for the link. i've taken a look on it before but my problem is, what can i do so that it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a test using 150 columns (151 including the id column) and thus :-

`2022-05-11 06:29:50.050 16308-16308/a.a.so72188145javaroommaxcolumns D/INSERTSQL: INSERT INTO newtable (id,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19,col20,col21,col22,col23,col24,col25,col26,col27,col28,col29,col30,col31,col32,col33,col34,col35,col36,col37,col38,col39,col40,col41,col42,col43,col44,col45,col46,col47,col48,col49,col50,col51,col52,col53,col54,col55,col56,col57,col58,col59,col60,col61,col62,col63,col64,col65,col66,col67,col68,col69,col70,col71,col72,col73,col74,col75,col76,col77,col78,col79,col80,col81,col82,col83,col84,col85,col86,col87,col88,col89,col90,col91,col92,col93,col94,col95,col96,col97,col98,col99,col100,col101,col102,col103,col104,col105,col106,col107,col108,col109,col110,col111,col112,col113,col114,col115,col116,col117,col118,col119,col120,col121,col122,col123,col124,col125,col126,col127,col128,col129,col130,col131,col132,col133,col134,col135,col136,col137,col138,col139,col140,col141,col142,col143,col144,col145,col146,col147,col148,col149,col150) SELECT id,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19,col20,col21,col22,col23,col24,col25,col26,col27,col28,col29,col30,col31,col32,col33,col34,col35,col36,col37,col38,col39,col40,col41,col42,col43,col44,col45,col46,col47,col48,col49,col50,col51,col52,col53,col54,col55,col56,col57,col58,col59,col60,col61,col62,col63,col64,col65,col66,col67,col68,col69,col70,col71,col72,col73,col74,col75,col76,col77,col78,col79,col80,col81,col82,col83,col84,col85,col86,col87,col88,col89,col90,col91,col92,col93,col94,col95,col96,col97,col98,col99,col100,col101,col102,col103,col104,col105,col106,col107,col108,col109,col110,col111,col112,col113,col114,col115,col116,col117,col118,col119,col120,col121,col122,col123,col124,col125,col126,col127,col128,col129,col130,col131,col132,col133,col134,col135,col136,col137,col138,col139,col140,col141,col142,col143,col144,col145,col146,col147,col148,col149,col150 FROM oldtable;`

Worked fine (Room 2.5.0-aplha01 and Android 30 emulator). I suspect that the issue may not be the number of columns but elsewhere in the SQL.

- The above SQL was extracted from the log, it was output to the log exactly as was then used (see testing code below).

A work-around **IF you have columns that can be null and a sufficient number of them to circumvent the issue**. Have an INSERT that inserts a manageable number of columns allowing the other columns to default to null, followed by 1 or more UPDATEs to apply the subsequent values to override the nulls.

Another work-around could be to extract all columns `SELECT * ....` into a Cursor and then build a `ContentValues` from the Cursor (on a per row basis) and use the `SupportSQliteDatabase`'s **`insert`** method. Something along the lines of:-

```
        Cursor csr = database.query("SELECT * FROM oldtable");
        database.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            cv.clear();
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                if (!csr.getColumnName(i).equals("col133")) { //<<<<< skip col133 as an example
                    cv.put(csr.getColumnName(i),csr.getString(i));
                }
            }
            database.insert("newTable", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE,cv);
        }
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
```

**Full code used for testing**

- Note that the only change between the 2 is the version number. So initially the code is run (after uninstalling the App) with version 1 (so no Migration). To test it's just a matter, of then changing the version to 2.

The `@Entity` annotated class **OldTable**:-

```
@Entity
class OldTable {
   @PrimaryKey
   Long id=null;
   String col1;
   String col2;
   String col3;
   .... (i.e. all missing numbers)
   String col147;
   String col148;
   String col149;
   String col150;
}
```

The @Dao annotated interface (not actually used) **AllDao**

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long insert(OldTable oldTable);

}
```

The @Database annotated class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = {OldTable.class},version = MainActivity.DATABASE_VERSION,exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase INSTANCE = null;
    static TheDatabase getINSTANCE(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,MainActivity.DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    static Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0; i < MainActivity.column_count;i++) {
                columns.add("col" + (i+1));
                if (i>0) {
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb2.append(",");
                }
                sb.append(columns.get(i));
                sb2.append(columns.get(i)).append(" TEXT");
            }
            String columnsAsCSV = sb.toString();
            String columnDefs = sb2.toString();

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newtable");
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + columnDefs + ");");
            String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO newtable (id,"+columnsAsCSV+") SELECT id,"+columnsAsCSV+" FROM oldtable;";
            Log.d("INSERTSQL",insertSQL);
            database.execSQL(insertSQL);
        }
    };
}
```

And finally putting it alltogether **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public static final int column_count = 150;
    private ArrayList<String> column_names = new ArrayList<>();
    private String allColumnsAsCSV = "";

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BuildColumns();

        db = TheDatabase.getINSTANCE(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        SupportSQLiteDatabase supdb = db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0;i < 100; i++) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("INSERT INTO oldtable (").append(allColumnsAsCSV).append(") VALUES(");
            for(int ii=0;ii<column_count;ii++) {
                if (ii > 0) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                sb.append("'").append(column_names.get(ii)).append(i).append(ii).append("'");
            }
            sb.append(")");
            supdb.execSQL(sb.toString());
        }
    }

    void BuildColumns() {
        column_names.clear();
        allColumnsAsCSV = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i < column_count; i++) {
            column_names.add("col" + (i+1));
            if (i>0) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(column_names.get(i));
        }
        allColumnsAsCSV = sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: MikeT: thx for your beautiful explained answer. 
My mistake was: I put this code in my BaseApplication class to catch RxJava exception. RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { logCrashlytics(message = it.message.toString()) Logger.error("OnErrorNotImplementedException: $it") } 

And it blocks me to see that there are errors in my migration requests. I've fixed them and migration works perfectly